# XSP Partial Refresh

Tags: xpages, lotus, xpages-ssjs

I am trying to send a value to server from anchor link and I call following code from a function which is called from the anchor link. Although I am able to trigger partial refresh,I get an error...any pointers please.....

```
var refreshId=dojo.query('[id$="testPanel"]')[0];
      alert(refreshId.innerHTML)
        alert(refreshId.id)
    var mySubmitValue='whatYouWantToSendHere';
    XSP.partialRefreshGet(refreshId, {
         params: {
          '$$xspsubmitvalue': mySubmitValue
         },
         onStart: function () {
               alert('starting');
         },
         onComplete: function () {
               alert('Complete');
         },
         onError:'myErrHandler( arguments[0], arguments[1] )'

    });
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you get? Did you you check browser console? Also rather than using `dojo.query` you can actually write like this - `XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:testPanel}", {...`

Comment: args -> [object Object] [object]
url -> http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX/MobFrameWrk.nsf/m_MobPage.xsp?openpage&db=testdev.nsf&unid=2638E3B470B9C3C843257AB700290BE0&pag=doc&$$ajaxid=%5Bobject%20HTMLDivElement%5D [string]
query -> view%3A_id1%3AdjTextBox1=&%24%24viewid=!dbleskmjcn!&%24%24xspsubmitid=%5Bobject%20HTMLDivElement%5D&%24%24xspexecid=&%24%24xspsubmitvalue=A1856F5D79CF162B43257AB6004EF4EE&%24%24xspsubmitscroll=0%7C0&view%3A_id1=view%3A_id1 [string]
handleAs -> text [string]
xhr -> [object XMLHttpRequest] [object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the object to the server. Use the **id** of the element instead:

```
XSP.partialRefreshGet(refreshId.id, {
```

Comment: Thanks Sven, Naveen.It worked when I kept the code same and instead of the ID of panel, replaced with ID of AppPage of singlePageApp. The finding was that ---- partial refresh of panel inside AppPage gives error.