# Activate a button in Xpages via jQuery

Tags: jquery, xpages-ssjs

I would like to run some server side JavaDcript.

However I would like to do that via jQuery since I am waiting for a AJAX request performed by jQuery.

The server side JavaScript may be on the onclick event for a button.

I wonder how I can initiate the `onclick` event via client side JavaScript?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/trigger ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples of triggering SSJS from a client. You will need to use

```
XSP.partialRefreshGet
```

or

```
XSP.partialRefreshPost
```

see here: [XSP Partial Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398980/xsp-partial-refresh/13399656#13399656)

You can use then params property section to manage what gets executed in your SSJS.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("#{id:ButtonID}").click();

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery in xPages is a little bit tricky. The Domino Server assigns a new dynamic name which contains colons to the field at run time. Colons are special characters in jQuery, so there is no chance to get a field by $('id'). You could use the class-name instead. 
If you want to use the id, have a look at this xSnippet provided by Mark Roden:

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=x-jquery-selector-for-xpages